# Can't decode bitmap file from camera

Tags: android

I'm trying to take a photo with native device camera. Im' starting with sending intent:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getMainActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Camera starts, file is created, I'm taking a photo and then this photo is received and decoded with this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);

        if (bitmap == null) {
            Crashlytics.log("Bitmap factory returned null");
        }

        mImageCropper.setBitmapPhoto(bitmap);
        expand(mMainImage);
    }
}
```

This is method that creates file and remember it's path:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    if (!image.exists()) {
        Log.e("take photo", "can't create photo file");
        Crashlytics.logException(new NullPointerException("Can't read photo from camera"));
    } else {
        Log.d("take photo", "photo file created " + image.getPath());
    }

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

But **sometimes** I got error with decoding this bitmap:

```
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

When I restart device (Nexus 5 (6.0 Marshmallow), but it occurs on other devices also) first run of this procedure is OK, but then errors start to occur. I can't reproduce this error on genymotion emulator (Nexus 5, 5.0)

**Update - reason and workaround**

It seems that native android camera application returns it's result before the bitmap is fully written down to the persistent storage. The code that I'm not proud of, but still it works:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Runnable decodeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);

                if (bitmap == null && counter < 20) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
                }
                mImageCropper.setBitmapPhoto(bitmap);
                expand(mMainImage);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(decodeRunnable, 100);
}
```

As you see this method will try to decode bitmap up to 20 times with 200 ms breaks between attempts. If you have better idea it would be welcome.

Comment: `mCurrentPhotoPath` does not seem to have any ties to how you are creating the picture. What exactly is `mCurrentPhotoPath`?

Comment: I've added missing code fragment - createImageFile() method

Comment: Are you holding onto this value via `onSaveInstanceState()`? Bear in mind that your process may be terminated while the user's chosen camera app is in the foreground.

Comment: This is not this the cause -  path to file is exactly this same as it was created.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your attempts to help me - I think that it will be interesting case for you Mark.

Comment: Ever solved? @piotrpo

Comment: This is so annoying! And exactly how you described. After a while it is possible to load image bitmap, but not immediately...

Answer (score 0):

I created an AsyncTask to handle this issue, till we find a more elegant way to handle this i decided to use [this one here](https://gist.github.com/yayaa/455e261270d6ccc003d38edb8034b055).